# Pandas regex to match a hyphen separated string

Tags: regex, pandas, python-3.7

I am trying to match a pattern in Pandas using regex

The pattern is a sequence of alphanumerics, separated by a hyphen

```
s1 = pd.Series(['b064571d-9d72-4225-8ccf-5528622c5680', 'dog', 'house and parrot', '23', np.NaN])
```

The first element in the series is the pattern I want to match (8x - 4x - 4x - 4x - 12x, where x is an alphanumeric character)

I have tried

```
s1.str.contains('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', regex=True)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4      NaN
```

But I dont know the syntax for the 8 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 12 pattern?
Any help appreciated
thanks

Comment: You mean `s1.str.contains(r'\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}){3}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}\b')`.

Comment: `s1.str.match('\w{8}-(\w{4}-){3}\w{12}')`?

Comment: thanks both - I could get the second response to generalise easier with my  poor knowledge of regex!